# Performance optimizing looped string concatenations in c#

Tags: c#, string, performance, string-concatenation

I have an application which processes some historical data.
I did some performance profiling and identified the following function as the new Bottleneck:

```
public string GenerateSaveStringOptimized()
{
    StringBuilder saveString = new StringBuilder();
    saveString.Append( $"{this.TimeOfDay},{this.DayOfMonth},{this.DayOfYear},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage3h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage6h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage1d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage6d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage12d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage24d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage48d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage96d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.RSI3h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.RSI6h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.RSI1d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.RSI6d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.RSI12d) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.Momentum1h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.SpotPrices1h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.BuyPrices1h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    foreach (float value in this.SellPrices1h) saveString.Append($"{value},");
    saveString.Append($"{this.Label}");
    return saveString.ToString();
}
```

[image]

The Result will be a string in csv format such as:

> 0,1,1,0.4916667,0.4916667,0.4916667,0.4916667,0.4916667,0.49,0.49,0.49,0.49,0.4897351,
> [...]

Each of those arrays contains 25 float values so the code is similar to the following pseudocode:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < 25 b++)
    {
        saveString.Append("Value,")
    }
}
```

that makes 17 * 25 = 425 string concatenations for each call of that function!

Is there a way I can optimize it?

The Top performance eater seems to be "waiting for cpu" and "AppendformatHelper" which is a builtin Method from StringBuilder. Unfortunately not something where I know how to treat that easily
[image]

Maybe with a Hardcoded Setup as the following?

```
saveString.Append($"{MA3h[0]},{MA3h[1]},{MA3h[2]},...");
saveString.Append($"{MA6h[0]},{MA6h[1]},{MA6h[2]},...");
saveString.Append($"{MA1d[0]},{MA1d[1]},{MA1d[2]},...");
```

A great Success was made by using the following loops instead:

```
foreach (float value in this.RSI1d)
{
    saveString.Append(value.ToString());
    saveString.Append(',');
}
```

A very Big thank you to user1672994, Guru Stron and Theodor Zoulias

The other mentions in the comments will be tried as well.

Comment: I'd look at using `.AppendFormat` first. You're producing a lot of additional overhead/garbage by running everything to append through string interpolation. It's also worth investigating what you're using the `StringBuilder` for -- if you're ultimately (say) writing to a file, then it's far more efficient to use a `StreamWriter` directly rather than building the whole thing in memory first.

Comment: That and giving an initial length to the `StringBuilder` in its constructor so it can allocate a bunch of memory up front rather than expanding during execution.

Comment: Since it appears you're concatenating the values of a bunch of enumerables, you may want to look into [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1). No idea if it's faster, but I can't imagine it's slower...

Comment: Hello Both, thank you for the hints. Unfortunately Streamwriter is a terrible decision for my case. I read and write from the same Disk which will throttle the IO Speed terribly. For that reason I buffer the output strings in an array to have a Bunch of lines before moving on.

Comment: If you need more buffering than the default streams apply, there's `BufferedStream` (`FileStream` allows customizing the buffer in the constructor too, but there's likely OS limits on that). Building up large strings in a `StringBuilder` only to fold those back into string instances you then store in an array is a big burden on the garbage collector.

Comment: Okay, gotta test that.  Gc takes away 22% of my performance.. That was a topic I originally planned to look into at a later point (don't know soo much about the GC yet)

Comment: There are comparison done at [here](https://www.meziantou.net/stringbuilder-performance-pitfalls.htm) which can help you to lead to an approach.

Comment: Also try using `$"{value.ToString()},"` it should prevent unnecessary boxing.

Comment: @GuruStron or even better simply `value.ToString()`, without the interpolation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey after studying a bit the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/a48449cb48a9a693903668a71449ac719b76867c/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L204), the `String.Join` should be faster because it preallocates an "unsafe" char buffer of exactly the right size.

Comment: Thank you for all the Suggestions. The value.ToString() did a blast already. That "{value}" was from the previous concatenation. Thank you for that! And I have been able to use the link from user1672994 rather than one Append("{value},") I do one Append(value.ToString()); Append(',');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preallocate a sufficient amount of capacity.

```
StringBuilder saveString = new StringBuilder(100000);
```

Don't use formatting or interpolation.

```
saveString.Append(this.TimeOfDay).Append(',').Append(this.DayOfMonth).Append(',').Append(this.DayOfYear).Append(',');
```

Perform similar substitutions in all loops.

```
foreach (float value in this.MovingAverage3h) saveString.Append(value).Append(',');
```

Don't use formatting or interpolation.

```
saveString.Append(this.Label);
```

---

The `Append` method has an overload that accepts `float`, so there will be no boxing.

Comment: I read the comments. It turns out that there already have all these tricks. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: no, since there is none yet. The capacity, is it the approximate length in chars for the final string or bits/bytes?

Comment: string.join seems way faster.. But still it already 4 folded the application performance...